# Form to execute serial port command and exit after 5 seconds

Tags: c#, serial-port

I need a .exe that when executed it performs a serial communication. They script is working fine but I need it to make it work without clicking the button (just by executing it) and after 5 seconds to quit the .exe. Make sense?

Below the code I have and is working if I click the button:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace XXXX
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        TopMost = true;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM2";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        serialPort1.Open();
        serialPort1.Write("XXXX\r");
        serialPort1.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: did I understand it right: the program should show up, send a serial port command and close? Is that your goal?

Comment: Yes @MarcoSadowski, that's my goal. Execute, send serial port command and close after 5 seconds.

Comment: @cokestone, please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Please go back to all your questions that have answers and accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the code in the `Form.Shown` Event so that the command only fire when the form is loaded. With `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep` you can let your application wait for some time.

```
    private void Form1_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM2";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        serialPort1.Open();
        serialPort1.Write("XXXX\r");
        serialPort1.Close();
        //will stop the executing thread for given amount of time. However if you want remain responsive (UI doesn't freeze) you might consider timers.
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        //close the application
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: @cokestone oh sorry if forgot it. I edited my answer. You just need to add `Application.Exit`